# jQuery script issue that provide a user with a popup dialog box with two PB. One to continue with the Session and another to end the Session

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, timeout-dialog.js

I have a web application where I am trying to implement code for Session Timeout. I got a .js file that gives user choice to "continue with the current session" or "End Session" PB

However if user clicks on "continue with the current session" PB, session is still time out.

Please tell me what is wrong with this script: Here is the code

timeout-dialog.js:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var s = this,
      i = arguments.length;

  while (i--) {
    s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
  }
  return s;
};

!function($) {
  $.timeoutDialog = function(options) {

    var settings = {
      timeout: 1200,
      countdown: 60,
      title: 'Employee TimeOut Session',
      message: 'Your session will expire in {0} seconds.',
      question: 'press OK to remain logged in.',
      keep_alive_button_text: 'Yes, Keep me signed in',
      sign_out_button_text: 'No, Sign me out',
      keep_alive_url: '/keep-alive',
      logout_url: null,
      logout_redirect_url: '/',
      restart_on_yes: true,
      dialog_width: 350
    }

    $.extend(settings, options);

    var TimeoutDialog = {
      init: function () {
        this.setupDialogTimer();
      },

      setupDialogTimer: function() {
        var self = this;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           self.setupDialog();
        }, (settings.timeout - settings.countdown) * 1000);
      },

      setupDialog: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.destroyDialog();

        $('<div id="timeout-dialog">' +
            '<p id="timeout-message">' + settings.message.format('<span id="timeout-countdown">' + settings.countdown + '</span>') + '</p>' +
            '<p id="timeout-question">' + settings.question + '</p>' +
          '</div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
          modal: true,
          width: settings.dialog_width,
          minHeight: 'auto',
          zIndex: 10000,
          closeOnEscape: false,
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false,
          dialogClass: 'timeout-dialog',
          title: settings.title,
          buttons : {
            'keep-alive-button' : {
              text: settings.keep_alive_button_text,
              id: "timeout-keep-signin-btn",
              click: function() {
                self.keepAlive();
              }
            },
            'sign-out-button' : {
              text: settings.sign_out_button_text,
              id: "timeout-sign-out-button",
              click: function() {
                self.signOut(true);
              }
            }
          }
        });

       self.startCountdown();
      },

      destroyDialog: function() {
        if ($("#timeout-dialog").length) {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $('#timeout-dialog').remove();
        }
      },

      startCountdown: function() {
        var self = this,
            counter = settings.countdown;

        this.countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
          counter -= 1;
          $("#timeout-countdown").html(counter);

          if (counter <= 0) {
            //window.clearInterval(self.countdown);
            self.signOut(false);
          }

        }, 1000);
      },

      keepAlive: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.destroyDialog();
        //window.clearInterval(this.countdown);
        $.get(settings.keep_alive_url, function(data) {
          if (data == "OK") {
            if (settings.restart_on_yes) {
              self.setupDialogTimer();
            }
          }
          else {
            self.signOut(false);
          }
        });
      },

      signOut: function(is_forced) {
        var self = this;
        this.destroyDialog();

        if (settings.logout_url != null) {
            $.post(settings.logout_url, function(data){
                self.redirectLogout(is_forced);
            });
        }
        else {
            self.redirectLogout(is_forced);
        }
      },

      redirectLogout: function(is_forced){
        var target = settings.logout_redirect_url + '?next=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        if (!is_forced)
          target += '&timeout=t';
        window.location = target;
      }
    };

    TimeoutDialog.init();
  };
}(window.jQuery);




.aspx code:

These are my reference in
<head>

          <script src="Comm/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="Comm/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="Comm/timeout-dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/timeout-dialog.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

</head>


In the<body> section

<body>

       <script type="text/javascript">
             var timeLeft = <%= Session.Timeout * 60 %>;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.timeoutDialog({ timeout: timeLeft, countdown: 10, logout_redirect_url: '../sessionLogout.htm', restart_on_yes: false });
                });
     </script>

....
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your keep-alive url returns "OK" as it is what the code is looking for.

```
$.get(settings.keep_alive_url, function(data) {
      if (data == "OK") {
        if (settings.restart_on_yes) {
          self.setupDialogTimer();
        }
      }
      else {
        self.signOut(false);
      }
```